# Download latest artifact from Azure Devops using Powershell - get buildId

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, build, artifact

I try to download the latest Artifact from AzureDevops with PowerShell.

Here is my script to get the latest buildid:

```
$organisation="aaa"
$project="bbb"
$personalAccessToken="ccc"


$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}


$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organisation/$project/_apis/build/latest/1?branchName=main" 

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $headers
```

When I execute this, I get the exception

> Build pipeline 1 was not found.

Can someone help me, where I can get the correct definitionId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Download latest artifact from Azure Devops using Powershell - get buildId

To get the latest artifact from the build, we need to provide the parameter `definitions` and the `$top` for the REST API [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&$top={$top}&branchName={branchName}&api-version=6.0
```

**Note:** The branch name parameter should include the `refs/heads`

As test with postman:

[image]

And if you want to know the correct definitionId, you could open the pipeline in the web page， it in the URL:

[image]